# omniauth requires Ruby version >= 2.1.9. issue while installing gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, omniauth, gemfile

Got an error after typing "bundle install" with some sort of issue with the Ruby version. Have been installed many-many gems so far and never got incompabilities with the Ruby version.

What's the best way to upgrade the Ruby version to get back on track with the "bundle install" without putting the app at "risk"?

Here it is what I have done:

1st - Added the twitter omniauth gem to my gemfile.

2nd - Created a omniauth.rb file in the app/config/initializers folder.

3rd - Typed the "bundle install" command and got the following error: "omniauth requires Ruby version >= 2.1.9."

Comment: The ruby version requirement was added to version `v1.5.0` of the gem - so you could maybe just use `v1.4.2` for now.

Comment: But if you're asking "how do I migrate the app", then the answer is quite obvious -- One step at a time, with lots of testing! This is a very broad question however, and well beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: No, I wasn't asking to how do I migrate the app. I would solely like to be able to install the gem, that's it. If I need to update the Ruby version, so be it. How come though? I wrote «gem install omniauth -v '1.4.2'» and neverthless... once I make the bundle install, I receive the same error over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies can specify a `required_ruby_version` in their `.gemspec` file. In this case, one of your sub-dependencies (omniauth - a sub-dependency of omniauth-oauth, which is in turn a sub-dependency of omniauth-twitter) has had such a requirement [since v1.5.0](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/releases/tag/v1.5.0).

To get a working install, you've got two options:

1. Pin to an older version of omniauth, by adding `gem "omniauth", "~> 1.4.2"` to your Gemfile. This will ensure Bundler uses an older version of omniauth. **However**, that may cause conflicts with other gems, leaving you with the same problem - indeed, it's probably the reason Bundler didn't automatically try to install an older version.
2. Update your Ruby version. If you have a `.ruby-version` file in your application, update the version there to `2.1.9`. Similarly if your `Gemfile` has a `ruby "..."` line in it, update that too. You'll probably also need to install the new version of Ruby locally - with rbenv you can use `$ rbenv install 2.1.9`, or if you use RVM try `$rvm install 2.1.9`.

My recommendation would be option 2 (updating your Ruby version).